# C# Resistor Closest Standard Value

Tags: c#

I have created a function that calculates closest standard value that is less or equal than entered value, but I gives me number that is bigger than entered value!!!
For example when I enter 1344 Ohms it gives me 1500 Ohms as closest standard value instead of 1200 Ohms!!!

```
int i = 0;
        string[] colours = new string[] { "Black", "Brown", "Red", "Orange", "Yellow", "Green", "Blue", "Violet", "Grey", "White", "Silver", "Gold" };
        Dictionary<char, double> factorDictionary = new Dictionary<char, double>() { { 'm', 0.001 }, { 'R', 1 }, { 'K', 1000 }, { 'M', 1000000 }, { 'G', 1000000000 } };
        string res = string.Empty;
        double p;
        List<double> E6 = new List<double> { 1, 1.5, 2.2, 3.3, 4.7, 6.8, 10 };
        List<double> E12 = new List<double> { 1, 1.2, 1.5, 1.8, 2.2, 2.7, 3.3, 3.9, 4.7, 5.6, 6.8, 8.2, 10 };
        List<double> E24 = new List<double> { 1, 1.1, 1.2, 1.3, 1.5, 1.6, 1.8, 2.0, 2.2, 2.4, 2.7, 3.0, 3.3, 3.6, 3.9, 4.3, 4.7, 5.1, 5.6, 6.2, 6.8, 7.5, 8.2, 9.1, 10 };
private void Closest_Standard_Value(double val)
        {
            while (p <= val)
            {
                if (val.ToString().Length == 1)
                {
                    p = E12[i] * 1;
                }
                if (val.ToString().Length == 2)
                {
                    p = E12[i] * 10;
                }
                if (val.ToString().Length == 3)
                {
                    p = E12[i] * 100;
                }
                if (val.ToString().Length == 4)
                {
                    p = E12[i] * 1000;
                }
                if (val.ToString().Length == 5)
                {
                    p = E12[i] * 10000;
                }
                if (val.ToString().Length == 6)
                {
                    p = E12[i] * 100000;
                }
                if (val.ToString().Length == 7)
                {
                    p = E12[i] * 1000000;
                }
                if (val.ToString().Length == 8)
                {
                    p = E12[i] * 10000000;
                }
                if (val.ToString().Length == 9)
                {
                    p = E12[i] * 100000000;
                }
                if (val.ToString().Length == 10)
                {
                    p = E12[i] * 1000000000;
                }
                if (val.ToString().Length == 11)
                {
                    p = E12[i] * 10000000000;
                }
                if (val.ToString().Length == 12)
                {
                    p = E12[i] * 100000000000;
                }
                i++;
            }
        }

/////This function calculates colors of resistors using entered value/////
    private void Band_4()
            {
                double val, mul;
                if (radioButton1.Checked)
                {
                    if (textBox1.Text == "0")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Otpornost mora biti veca od nule!", "Otpornost", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        return;
                    }
                    if (comboBox1.Text == "")
                    {
                        MessageBox.Show("Izaberi vrednost tolerancije!", "Otpornost", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                        return;
                    }

                    while (string.IsNullOrEmpty(res))
                    {
                        res = textBox1.Text;
                    }

                    var lastChar = res.Last();
                    var isUnitCorrect = factorDictionary.ContainsKey(lastChar);
                    var value = res.Substring(0, res.Length - 1);
                    var isValueCorrect = !value.Any(x => !char.IsDigit(x));

                    if (isUnitCorrect && isValueCorrect)
                    {
                        mul = factorDictionary[lastChar];
                        val = double.Parse(value) * mul;
                        int third = 0;

                        if (val < 0.1)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Otpornost ne moze da bude manja od 0.1 oma!", "Otpornost", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                            return;
                        }
                        if (val < 1)
                        {
                            val *= 100;
                            third = 10;
                        }
                        else if (val < 10)
                        {
                            val *= 10;
                            third = 11;
                        }

                        res = val.ToString();

                        Closest_Standard_Value(val);

                        if (res.Count() > 24)
                        {
                            MessageBox.Show("Pogresna vrednost!", "Otpornost", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Error);
                            return;
                        }

                        else
                        {
                            label14.BackColor = Color.FromName(colours[res[0] - '0']);
                            label15.BackColor = Color.FromName(colours[res[1] - '0']);
                            label16.BackColor = Color.FromName(colours[third != 0 ? third : res.Count() - 2]);
                            textBox2.Text = colours[res[0] - '0'];
                            textBox3.Text = colours[res[1] - '0'];
                            textBox4.Text = colours[third != 0 ? third : res.Count() - 2];
                            label3.Text = Convert.ToString(p);
                            Entered_Value(val, lastChar);
                        }
                    }
                    if (radioButton1.Checked)
                    {
                        if (comboBox1.Text == "E24 (5%)")
                        {
                            label17.BackColor = Color.Gold;
                            textBox5.Text = "Gold";
                        }
                        if (comboBox1.Text == "E12 (10%)")
                        {
                            label17.BackColor = Color.Silver;
                            textBox5.Text = "Silver";
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
```

Comment: I understand nothing of this code, but the loop _while(p <= val)_ exits only when p is bigger than val

Comment: Your `Closest_Standard_Value` method does not make any sense. What is `p` and what is `i`?

Comment: i variable is for going through the list E12 and p is where goes calculated closest standard value!

Comment: None of the variables is declared and `p` is never modified. As I said, it does not make sense.

Comment: You should really refactor this code...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

it's because you're always incrementing `i` after every `p` setting, so you should initialize `i=-1` and check the `E12[i+1]`

also, your `Closest_Standard_Value()` method code can be *heavily* reduced to the following:

```
    public void Closest_Standard_Value(double val)
    {
        while (E12[i + 1] * Math.Pow(10, val.ToString().Length - 1) <= val)
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
```

or, not to repeat that `Math.Pow()` at every iteration:

```
    public void Closest_Standard_Value(double val)
    {
        val = val * Math.Pow(10, -(val.ToString().Length - 1));
        while (E12[i + 1] <= val)
        {
            i++;
        }
    }
```

Finally, two more annotations:

- you conceived your method as a `Void` one so it isn't returning any value

  if you wanted to return the `List` element you searched for then you'd write it as follows

  ```
  public double Closest_Standard_Value(double val)
  {
      int decimals = val.ToString().Length - 1;
      val = val * Math.Pow(10, -decimals);            
      while (E12[i + 1]<= val)
          i++;

      return E12[i]*Math.Pow(10, decimals);
  }
  ```
- you're actually assuming that the *real* `type` of `val` is `int`, otherwise should they pass some `2.2` as `val` parameter then `val.ToString().Length` would return `3` instead of the expected `1`

  if you want to let *real* `double` be passed as `val` and have your method treat it properly then you should adopt the following code:

  ```
  public double Closest_Standard_Value(double val)
  {
      int decimals = ((int)val).ToString().Length - 1;
      val = val * Math.Pow(10, -decimals);            
      while (E12[i + 1]<= val)
          i++;

      return E12[i]*Math.Pow(10, decimals);
  }
  ```

Comment: It's working now! Thank you very much!!!

Comment: you are welcome. you may want to mark answer as accepted. thank you

Comment: Form some values code does not work well: https://postimg.org/image/qkh8u1v0x/ https://postimg.org/image/5c85qd5xt/

Comment: What values are giving you issues?

Comment: For example when I enter 120K it gives me1.2M for closest standard value

Comment: Are you entering 120000 or 120K?

Comment: I am entering 120K

Comment: You have to enter 120000 since your method accepts a 'double' as input argument. Should you want to enter both numbers or combinations of number and strings then you have to implement some sort of deciphering code. Finally, since I solved your_original_ problem please mark snswer as accepted. Thank you.